# shapefile does not overlap in R

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, r

I have got a shapefile, and a GeoTIFF image. I want to crop my GeoTIFF based on my shapefile. EASY ! but I don't know I get lots of error.

I tried

```
library(raster)
xp <- raster("c:/test/M145.tif")  ## 1
shp <- shapefile("c:/shapefile/Indy_Bdry.shp")
crop(xp, shp)
```

but I get error that the extents do not overlap! so I try to change the projection of the shapefile as follow, but still I get the same error.

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
P4S.latlon <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84")
indy.shp <- readShapePoly("C:/shapefile/tl_2013_18_cousub.shp", verbose=TRUE, proj4string=P4S.latlon)
writeOGR(indy.shp, dsn = getwd(), layer = "Indy_Bdry", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

I also tried this one, and I get error of "unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spTransform’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "CRS""

```
library(raster)
library(Rgdal)
xp <- readOGR("c:/test/M145.tif")
sh <- readOGR("c:/shapefile/tl_2013_18_cousub.shp")
myExtent <- spTRansform(xp,sh, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84"))
```

The link is the shapefile and example of image!

[shapefile](https://ufile.io/4agjj)

[image](https://ufile.io/8fikm)

Comment: You cannot use readOGR to read a raster, use raster::raster, raster::stack or rgdal::readGDAL. Use proj4string() not CRS(). You can pull it directly from the target object ie., spTransform(xp,sh, proj4string(xp))

Comment: it does not change anything...I tried that as well

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: It's working but it does not crop my area based on my shape file, it creates a rectangular rather than creating based on my shapefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is up with your workflow but, you are over complicating things. The `raster::crop` function subsets the raster to a rectangular extent based on bounding coordinates (or and extent object). If you want to clip the raster to your polygons, you need to then apply the `raster::mask` function. This can actually be done in one-fell-swoop by nesting the functions (see example).

This code works just fine with your data.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(raster)

setwd("...")

xp <- raster("M145.tif") 
shp <- shapefile("tl_2013_18_cousub")

proj4string(xp)
proj4string(shp)

shp <- spTransform(shp, proj4string(xp)) 

plot(xp)
  plot(shp, add=T)

xp <- mask(crop(xp, extent(shp)), shp)  

plot(xp)
  plot(shp, add=T)
```

Comment: It's working but it does not crop my area based on my shape file, it creates a rectangular rather than creating based on my shapefile

Comment: raster::crop subsets to a a rectangular extent, if you want to clip to your polygon boundary, you then need to apply raster::mask see changes to the answer.